# Command Text Parameters as nothing

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am building a MySql query in vb.net:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "Select id INTO @idDep from dBase.tableA where guid in (@strdepToDelete, @strOtherToDelete) and IsDependent = '1'; " & _
                                  "Select id INTO @idOther from dBase.tableA where guid in (@strdepToDelete, @strOtherToDelete) and IsDependent = '0'; " & _
                                  "delete from dBase.tableA where id in(@idDep, @idOther);"
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@strdepToDelete", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.String)
                cmd.Parameters("@strdepToDelete").Value = strdepToDelete
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@strOtherToDelete", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.String)
                cmd.Parameters("@strdepToDelete").Value = strOtherToDelete
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdDep", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Int24)
                cmd.Parameters("@IdDep").Value = Nothing
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdOther", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Int24)
                cmd.Parameters("@IdOther").Value = Nothing


                Try
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    success = True
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
                Return success
```

Error is caught which indicates that Null cannnot be @IdDep value.  I have tried "" for value of that variable; I have tried ? for value of that variable.  When I run the command text gained from hovering over cmd in MySql it works as it should. My question is how to paramaterize queries with nothing value.

Comment: Try [DbNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Did that too and it choked saying it was a type and could not be used as a variable to right of equal sign

Comment: `DbNull.Value` or `New DbNull()`, then...

Comment: `System.DbNull.Value` would be the syntax...but that wont work either

Comment: I used DBNull.Value and got same "You have an error in your SQL syntax, check for right syntax to use near NULL from

Comment: I dont get syntax errors, but the query doesnt work right.

Comment: I think this is a SQLism.  If a column can be Null, then `IS NULL` is the only syntax that will work.. IN(...) and WHERE just work work.  if the SQL is ` Foo IS @p1` I can pass DBNull.Value but that is goofy.  Can you change the query to use `IS Null OR @foo IN (...)`?

Comment: Thanks -- solved issue by writing a delete query in commandText deleting from guid column where in (@strdepToDelete, @strOtherToDelete) which is ok to do because guids  are unique to row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your problem is the datatype, the command object is pretty good at inferring DBNull from Nothing.  I think your SQL statement is the problem...

If you have an IN statement, `FldNm IN(1,2,NULL)` then the SQL engine will parse it as `FldNm=1 OR FldNm=2 OR FldNm=NULL`.  That last item isn't valid (for SQL in general, and also for MySQL in particular ... just tried it to make verify).

**You can ask for records where FldNm IS NULL, but not where FldNm=NULL.**

So - when you construct that SQL statement, you'll need to skip the values in your IN clause if they are null.  OR - use some non-existent value if the value is null as a "work around."

Hope that's helpful!